# Ionic Push - Resetting plugins due to page load

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push

I'm building an app and I don't know why (I've check a lot of post on StackOverflow and beyond) when I'm running the app on my iPhone through Xcode I've a message "Resetting plugins due to page load." and the device ID I need for push is not set or given and I'm not asked for push authorization. All of that work with a ionic tab starter project.

[image: Screenshot]

I've remove jQuery (for open links in the built-in browser of the device) and retry but nothing change... I've try to remove my AppCtrl who is load before the other view but nothing change. I haven't found solution on the web so far.

Thank for your help,

percypyan